# Erbwörter mit x

Tags: spelling

Gibt es eine allgemein akzeptiere oder zumindest gut fundierte Erklärung dafür, dass es einige urgermanische Wörter mit /ks/ gibt, die statt mit *chs* oder ggf. *cks* mit *x* geschrieben werden, obwohl das eigentlich nur in Lehnwörtern vorkommt?

### Beispiele

- *Axt*
- *Hexe*
- *Nixe*
- *Faxe*
- *feixen*
- *ausbüxen* (norddt.)
- *Boxe* (engl.?)
- *Jux* (lat.?)

Mir fällt daneben ein Fall ein, dessen Standardschreibung im Begriff ist, von *chs* zu *x* zu wechseln: *Hachse* vs. *Haxe*. Laut [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Hachse) ist Letzteres nur eine regionale Variante.

### *chs*

- *sechs*
- *Dachs*
- *Flachs*
- *Fuchs*
- *Lachs*
- *Luchs*
- *Wachs*
- *Wuchs*, *Gewächs* < *wachsen*
- *Achse*
- *Ochse*
- *Echse*
- *Buchse*
- *Büchse*
- *Wichse*
- *Achsel*
- *Wechsel*
- *Weichsel*
- *Deichsel*
- *Drechsel(bank)*
- *Brachsen*
- *grochsen*
- (*Sachsen*)
- *flechsig*

### *cks*

- *Häcksel* < *hacken*
- *Klacks*
- *Klecks* < *kleckern*
- *Knacks* < *knacken*
- *Knicks* < *knicken*
- *Mucks* < *mucken*
- *Glucks* < *gluckern*
- *Gesocks*
- *(schnur)stracks*
- *zwecks* < *Zweck*
- *Schickse* (jidd.)

### *ks*

- *Schlaks* (norddt.)
- *Keks* < *cakes* (engl.)
- *Koks* < *cokes* (engl.)
- *Fleks* < *flakes* (engl.)

### *gs*

- *flugs* < *Flug*
- *tags* < *Tag*

Comment: Die letzen (ks-) Beispiele sind, wahrscheinlich bis auf "schlaksig", keine Erbwörter.

Comment: Deswegen habe ich zum Vergleich die Herkunft angegeben. Die meisten anderen Lehn- und Fremdwörter dürften mit _x_ geschrieben werden. Habe jetzt aber die Herkunft genauer ergänzt.

Comment: *Fleks* sagt mir nichts; wo ist das - und für was - in Gebrauch? Sollte es das aber wirklich geben, dann hättest du mit *Fleks* vs. *Flex* (Winkelschleifer) noch ein weiteres graphematisches Minimalpaar. - *Flex* als Wort für Winkelschleifer egal welchen Herstellers ist jedenfalls in Süddeutschland gebräuchlich.

Comment: _Haferfleks_ u.ä. findet man auf Müslipackungen.

Comment: @Crissov - Ehrlich? Für mich hört (bzw. liest) sich das an, als hätte da der Graphiker, der die Packung gestaltet hat, ein Sprachproblem. Gemeint sind wohl *Haferflocken*, und vielleicht wollte man cool sein und *Hafer-Flakes* sagen, aber *Haferfleks* klingt wirklich nach mangelnder Kenntnis des Deutschen. Ich achte aber mal drauf, ob ich so was auf Müslipackungen finde. Manchmal nimmt die Produktplazierersprache ja seltsame Wege.

Comment: Oh, _Haferfleks_ scheint ein Markenzeichen von _Kölln_ zu sein und keine allgemeine Bezeichnung.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann "mangelnder Kenntnis" vgl die Herkunft von Keks (auch oben in der Liste). Lustig dabei ist aber, dass ich eben, hier und jetzt bemerkt habe, dass da die Aussprache "flex" wohl gar nicht im Sinne des Erfinders sein wird… Übrigens sind sind diese Haferfleks® keine Flocken sondern Zuckerpuffware.

Comment: Ich kann nur vermuten, die Schreibung dieser pösen Wörter mit X ist ein Abwehrzauber, der an den gekreuzigten Herren Vater unser Jesus Maria der gesalbte erinnern sollte, Gott habe ihn gnädig. Das betrifft zumindest Hexe, Nixe, Faxe (faggotry) und Jux. Zwar dürfte Axt eher in ideographischer Darstellung zu suchen sein, nicht unähnlich ⚒️. Ausbüxen nur in abgenzung zu Büchse. Ob Boxe (?) dementsprechend verderbt für *Buchse*, *porcella* etc. steht, sei dahingestellt.

Answer (score 5):

### Axt

Mittelhochdeutsch (mhd): ackes
 Althochdeutsch (ahd): ackus
 Gotisch: aqizi

Aber auch:
 Altgriechisch: axī́nē (ἀξίνη)
 Latein: ascia (vergleiche auch: Achse, Achsel)

Bei dem Wort scheint es sich, entgegen deiner Annahme, gar nicht um ein *»urgermanisches«* Wort zu handeln. Es scheint vielmehr ein [Wanderwort](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wanderwort) zu sein, dessen etymologische Wurzeln nur schwer auszumachen sind.

Im [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Axt#et-1) steht zur modernen Schreibweise mit einem X:

> die Schreibweise mit x setzt im Spätmhd. ein und wird seit Luther üblich.

---

### Boxe

Weder das DWDS, noch Wiktionary noch ich kennen dieses Wort. Nicht einmal in der [Wortformenliste des Institus für deutsche Sprache](http://www1.ids-mannheim.de/kl/projekte/methoden/derewo.html) findet man dieses Nomen. Ich finde nur eine deklinierte Form des Verbs *»boxen«* (*»ich boxe«*), aber das ist ein Lehnwort, das im 18. Jahrhundert aus dem Englischen ins Deutsche importiert wurde.

Englisch ist zwar auch eine westgermanische Sprache, aber dort wird das X wesentlich häufiger verwendet als im Deutschen. Das X ist dort nichts ungewöhnliches, und somit ist es auch keine große Überraschung, wenn man es in Lehnwörtern findet, die aus dieser Sprache stammen.

---

### Hexe

mdh: hecse, hesse
 ahd: hagzissa, hazus, hagzus, hagazusa, ...
 altenglisch: hægtesse, hegtes

Die genaue Etymologie ist unklar, es wird aber vermutet, dass das Wort ursprünglich ein Kompositum war, zusammengesetzt aus:

- hag = Zaun, Hecke, Gehege
- tysia = Elfe, verkrüppelte Frau

  oder (2. Teil):
- tusul = Gespenst

Die ursprüngliche Bedeutung dürfte also »gespenstische Zaunreiterin« oder etwas ähnliches gewesen sein.

Das Wort ist also eindeutig ein germanisches Wort (sogar ein rein westgermanisches, denn weder in den norgermanischen Sprachen, noch im ausgestorbenen Ostgermanisch (Gotisch) gibt es damit verwandte Wörter).

Die Frage, warum aus der mittelhochdeutschen *hecse* dann die neuhochdeutsche *Hexe* wurde, ist somit durchaus berechtigt. Die von mir konsultierten Quellen gehen auf diese Frage nicht ein.

---

### Nixe

Das ist die weibliche Form des ursprünglich männlichen Wassergeistes *Nix* (der Nix).

- mdh: nickes
- ahd: nicchus

Das Wort hat sich aus einem Partizip des indogermanischen Verbs *neigu* (waschen) entwickelt, welches wiederum mit dem altgriechischen nízein (νίζειν) (sich waschen, baden) verwandt ist.

Dieses Wort wurde also auch sehr früh in den deutschen Wortschatz aufgenommen, und darf daher durchaus als Erbwort angesehen werden.

Auch hier konnte ich keine Begründung für den Wechseln von *nickes* zu *Nix* (bzw. Nixe) finden. Klar scheint zu sein, dass die Endsilbe *-es* als Reduktionssilbe den Vokal verloren hat, woraus (zumindest in der Aussprache) *nicks* wurde. Das Wort *Knicks* (höfliche Kniebeuge, stammt von *knicken* ab) hat die Endung *-icks* jedenfalls behalten, es ist aber auch erst seit dem 17. Jahrhundert belegt, also vergleichsweise jung.

Der Wandel vom *Nicks* zum *Nix* muss also vor dem 17. Jahrhundert stattgefunden haben.

---

### (aus)büxen

Das ist eine moderne Variante von *ausbüchsen*, die sich erst in den letzten 20 Jahren merklich verbreitet:

[image]

[Quelle](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=ausgeb%C3%BCxt%2C%20ausgeb%C3%BCchst&year_start=1800&year_end=2020&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Causgeb%C3%BCxt%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Causgeb%C3%BCchst%3B%2Cc0)

Ich konnte weder im DWDS noch im Duden (Herkunftswörterbuch) eine Beschreibung von (aus)büxen finden und auch nicht von (aus)büchsen. Es scheint aber auf der Hand zu liegen, dass damit ursprünglich entweder das Entkommen aus einer Büchse (Behälter) gemeint war, oder vielleicht auch die gelungene Flucht vor einer Büchse (Jagdwaffe).

Zur Schreibweise mit X:
 Offenbar finden es einige Autoren lustig, oder aus einem anderen Grund angebracht, hier *chs* durch *x* zu ersetzen, und offenbar sind so viele Menschen der Meinung, dass das eine gute Idee ist, dass sie es nachahmen. Es ist also - wie ich glaube - eine reine Modeerscheinung, bei der aber noch unklar ist, ob sie von Dauer sein wird, oder wieder verschwindet.

---

### feixen

Bei diesem Verb handelt es sich um eine Ableitung vom Nomen *Feix = Fuchs*, und zwar in der Bedeutung *angehender Student* (in Burschenschaften werden die neuen Mitglieder auch heute noch *Füchse* genannt).

Das Verb ist erst seit dem 19. Jahrhundert belegt (es gilt somit nicht gerade als wirklich urgermanisch). Es bedeutete ursprünglich *»dümmlich lachen«* und hat erst in jüngerer Zeit die Bedeutung *schadenfroh lachen, grinsen* angenommen.

Das Nomen *der Feix* ist seit dem 17. Jahrhundert belegt und dürfte sich in der norddeutschen Umgangssprache entwickelt haben. Es hat sich in dialekthafter Weise aus dem Wort *Fuchs* entwickelt. In der Verschriftlichung wollte man dann offenbar den Unterschied zwischen dem jungen Studenten und dem Tier auch sichtbar machen, und ersetze eben *chs* durch *x*. - Letzten Endes also auch eine Modeerscheinung, die sich dann dauerhaft etabliert hat.

---

### Faxe

Singular von *Faxen* (*Faxen machen*)

Dieses Wort geht über ein selten verwendetes Nomen (*»die Fickesfackes«*) als Zwischenstation auf das mundartliche Verb *»fickfacken«* mit der Bedeutung *»hin- und herlaufen«* zurück und ist erst seit dem 18. Jahrhundert belegt. Der Ursprung des Verbs *fickfacken* ist wiederum das Verb *»ficken«*, das in vielen Regionen neben der Hauptbedeutung *»den Geschlechtsverkehr ausüben«* auch noch die Bedeutung *»sich rasch hin und her bewegen«* hat, die einigen Quellen zufolge auch die ursprüngliche Bedeutung von *ficken* war. Andere Quellen legen nahe, dass das Wort *fuggen* (später *figgen*) die Wurzel von *ficken* sein könnte. Die Wörter *(ein)fügen* und die *Fuge* (Spalt zwischen zwei Werkstücken) stammen auch davon ab.

Was die Schreibweise mit X betrifft, gilt hier etwas ähnliches wie beim *feixen*: Ein Dialektwort wurde in einer Zeit in die Schriftform gebracht, in der der Buchstabe X zwar noch eine Besonderheit, aber bereits mit einer klaren Ausspracheregel belegt war. Offenbar lag es damals näher, den Laut [ks] in einem neu erfundenen Wort durch den Buchstaben X wiederzugeben.

---

### Jux

*»Jux«* ist auch ein relativ junges Wort. Es ist erst seit dem 18. Jahrhundert belegt, und wurde damals auch *»Jucks«* und *»Joks«* geschrieben. Es scheint sich in studentischen Kreisen als umgangssprachliches Wort aus dem Wort *»Jokus«* entwickelt haben, das seine Wurzel im lateinischen Wort *iocus* (Scherzrede, Scherz, Spaß) hat, und aus dem sich auch der *Joker* und der englische *joke* (Scherz) entwickelt haben.

Auch hier: Ein neu erfundenes Wort, das den Laut [ks] enthält, wurde von der gesprochenen Umgangssprache in die Schriftsprache übernommen. Unter mehreren verschiedenen Anfangsvarianten hat sich dann die Form mit dem X durchgesetzt.

---

### Zusammenfassung

Die Beispiele belegen eine Einführung des X zu sehr unterschiedlichen Zeiten (*Axt*: ca. um 1500 oder davor, *ausbüxen*: ca. um 2000), aber es scheint immer so gewesen zu sein, dass einige wenige anfingen sich Gedanken über die Schreibweise eines neuen Wortes zu machen, und sich dabei aus den unterschiedlichsten Gründen für das X entschieden. Die Mehrheit schloss sich im Lauf der Zeit dieser Schreibweise an (oder ist gerade dabei sich anzuschließen, wie der Fall *ausbüxen* belegt.)

Comment: Mir ging es tatsächlich hauptsächlich um _Axt, Hexe, Nixe_. Die anderen sind mir erst beim Schreiben und Recherchieren auf-/eingefallen. _Axt_ ist besonders, da es der einzige Wortstamm mit /kst/ ist. Eine Boxe findet man bspw. im Boxenlaufstall, wahrscheinlich eine Übernahme von engl. _box_.

Comment: @Crissov: Das, was du *Boxe* nennst, ist eine *Box* (ohne e) (Abteil in ein einem Stall), und das ist, wie du schon vermutet hast, ein englisches Lehnwort. Mir sind aber auch noch eingefallen: Die *Büx* (auch *Buxe*) = Hose aus Bocksleder; der Fex (komischer Kerl, z.B. Bergfex = fanatischer Bergsteiger) ist mit dem Feix (siehe *feixen*) verwandt; die Kraxe (ein Korb, den man auf dem Rücken trägt), abgeleitet vom Verb *kraxeln* = klettern in bayrischen Dialekten

Comment: Nee, es heißt zumindest regional tatsächlich _die Boxe_.

Comment: @Crissov: Das muss dann aber eine sehr kleine Region sein. Oder (und das vermute ich) es ist gar kein standarddeutsches Wort, sondern eine umgangssprachliche Variante oder ein Dialektwort (und somit ein Wort, das ausschließlich in der gesprochenen Sprache vorkommt, nicht aber in der Schriftform). Das würde nämlich auch erklären, warum es in keinem Wörterbuch steht. Nicht mal Google kann mit »Boxe« etwas sinnvolles anfangen.

Comment: [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Boxe) hat einen Eintrag, aber die Bedeutungsangabe ist sehr mager

Comment: Es gibt da mindesens die [Buxe](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buxe) and die [Büx](https://nds.wikipedia.org/wiki/Büx) und [Bokse](https://nds-nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bokse).

Comment: Am Rande sei erwähnt, dass inzwischen auch *"nix"* als umgangssprachlich für *"nichts"* im Duden steht..